# How big is the Loggregator buffer on Swisscom Application Cloud

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

The [documentation](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html#view) says:

`$ cf logs APP_NAME --recent`
displays all the lines in the Loggregator buffer.

How big is this buffer? Can I change it myself?

Comment: I cannot answer your question. But the ELK service could help you...

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer:  I don't work for Swisscom so I have no idea how their platform is configured.  That said, I believe I can still answer your questions.

> How big is this buffer?

I believe the value you're looking for is `doppler.maxRetainedLogMessages` which defaults to 100.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/loggregator/wiki/Loggregator-Component-Properties

That said, I would make the case that the number of lines buffered shouldn't matter.  The recent logs feature is purely a convenience and it's not mean for log storage.  If you're trying to use it in a way where you need to know specifically how much it will buffer then you're probably using it wrong and should probably consider a different option.

A couple common cases where the `--recent` buffer might not be large enough and solutions:

**Scenario 1**: You're troubleshooting (perhaps a failed app start or stage) and `cf logs --recent` doesn't show you enough information.

Run `cf logs` in a second terminal and repeat your action.  This will show you the entire log output saved locally on your machine.  You can also redirect to a file with `cf logs <app> > some-file.log`.

**Scenario 2**: You're running a production app.

You will want reliable log storage for a sustained and predictable amount of time.  In this case, you'll want to setup a log drain so that your logs are sent somewhere outside of the platform for long term storage.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/log-management.html#user-provided

If you've got another scenario, feel free to add a comment.  There is probably a different/better way to handle it.

> Can I change it myself?

The setting I mentioned above is configured by your platform operator.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

thanks [to Daniel Mikusa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45674835/1140727) for your insights and helpful explanation. I can confirm that Swisscom Application Cloud uses the default value.

Quote from our deployment manifest:

```
  loggregator:
    (...)
    maxRetainedLogMessages: 100
    outgoing_dropsonde_port: 8081
```